# OpenGL debugging

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

When I write OpenGL (1.0) programs for Android, I found it not easy to debug my programs. OpenGL is just a fixed pipeline of several steps which process vertex coordintates. Is there any way to peek and see what are results of consecutive steps of the pipeline?

Added: Mad Scientist, thanks for your advice. However, I tried to use Tracer for OpenGL ES (following instructions from http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html ) and I'm still not sure on how do I find the information I need. I can see slider to choose a frame, then I can see a list of functions called. When I choose one of functions, I can see GL state. But when I look (inside this GL state) at context 0 -> vertex array data -> generic vertex attributes, all coordinates I can see are zeroes. Is it normal? My main hope is that in those situations when I can see nothing but a black screen I would be able to see what are vertexes' coordinates before and after multiplication by matrices and this will help me find out why they are invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [OpenGL Tracer for Android](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html), it is part of the Android SDK. Just start the `Monitor` program and trace your App.

I found the Tracer a bit temperamental and it does not work with my Nexus 10, but if it works it provides a lot of information.